# Quicksort Multithreading

Tags: java, performance, loops, for-loop

I'd like to implement a quicksort algorthmus for a 2D array with multithreading.

Its working very fast in Single  thread, but now i Tried to speed it up. This is my code to sort every part of the 2d array correctly (the speed of the sorting algorithm himself should be very fast). Its directly working on the "c".

```
public static void sort(int[][] c) {
    int[][] a = new int[][] { { 0, -4, 1, 2 }, { 1, 0, 3 }, { 2, 3, 0 } };
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        sort(c[i],0,c[i].length-1);
    }

}
```

I tried up to know:
split the for loop in small "loopers" which perform a task of "x" loops, but this is slowing the algorithm.

Can someone help me to speed it up?

Comment: on how many elements the test was made ?

Comment: the array is something like [100_000] [75] size

Answer (score 0):

A couple of possibilities:

```
public static void sort(int[][] c) {
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        //sort(c[i],0,c[i].length-1);
        Arrays.sort(c[i]);
    }
}

public static void parallelSort(int[][] c) {
    Arrays.asList(c).parallelStream().forEach(d -> Arrays.sort(d));
}

public static void threadedSort(int[][] c) throws InterruptedException {
    int count = 4;
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        final int finalI = i;
        threads[i] = new Thread(
                () -> sortOnThread(c, (c.length / count) * finalI, c.length / count), 
                "Thread " + i
            );
        threads[i].start();
    }
    for (Thread thread : threads) {
        thread.join();
    }
}

private static void sortOnThread(int[][] c, int first, int length) {
    for (int i = first; i < first + length; i++) {
        Arrays.sort(c[i]);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    int[][] c = new int[10_000_000][75];

    shuffle(c);
    System.out.println("Starting sort()");
    long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
    sort(c);
    System.out.println("Took " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - before) + "ms");

    shuffle(c);
    System.out.println("Starting parallelSort()");
    before = System.currentTimeMillis();
    parallelSort(c);
    System.out.println("Took " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - before) + "ms");

    shuffle(c);
    System.out.println("Starting threadedSort()");
    before = System.currentTimeMillis();
    threadedSort(c);
    System.out.println("Took " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - before) + "ms");
}

private static void shuffle(int[][] c) {
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < c[i].length; j++)
            c[i][j] = j;
        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(c[i]));
    }
}
```

Which produced these timings on a quad core (i5-2430M):

```
Starting sort()
Took 2486ms
Starting parallelSort()
Took 984ms
Starting threadedSort()
Took 875ms
```

The `parallelStream()` approach was the least code, but clearly comes with a bit more overhead (sending each sort through the `ForkJoinPool`) than direct threading.  This was more noticable when the array was the smaller `[100_000] [75]`:

```
Starting sort()
Took 48ms
Starting parallelSort()
Took 101ms
Starting threadedSort()
Took 21ms
```

---

Just in case it's useful ... initially while coding this, I found the timings for the three approaches were much more similar:

```
Starting sort()
Took 2403ms
Starting parallelSort()
Took 2435ms
Starting threadedSort()
Took 2284ms
```

This turned out to be because I was naively allocating new sub-arrays each time in my `shuffle()` method.  Clearly this was generating a lot of extra GC work - even a short sleep before the calling the sort methods made all the difference.